# String comparison in for loop? (specifically in TC)

Tags: loops, batch-file, substring, teamcity

I want to take a bunch of files in folder, and do something if the file doesn't contain the word Microsoft.
I am working in Teamcity, but except for the amount of % before variables should be the same as batch files.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%%%v in (*.dll) do (
REM Do something that cif fails changes the errorlevel
echo !errorlevel!
set filename = %%%%~nv
echo !filename!
if !filename:Microsoft!==!filename! (
if !errorlevel! neq 0 goto :error
)
)
```

When I echo the errorlevel I get the correct result, however the filename echo isn't working, which implies I didn't set it correctly. Of course then the comparison is meaningless (it never gets into the if block).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the spaces in the `SET` command.  Rookie mistake.  What are you trying to do with the first `IF` command?

Comment: The comparison should be `if /i "!filename:Microsoft=!"=="!filename!" (`

Comment: In the if command I'm trying to work on files that don't include the string Microsoft

Comment: Ok.  LotPings fixed your code for that. You do realize that using the `GOTO` command will break out of the `FOR` command.  Might be better to use a `FOR /F` command to parse the output of the `DIR` command which would get piped to the `FIND` command. `FOR /F "delims=" %%G in ('dir /a-d /b /s *.dll ^|find /I /V "microsoft"') do ........`

Answer (score 0):

So the comments on my question were really all I needed, thanks!
In any case, if anyone else encounters this, here's the code that works:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /r %%%%v in (*.dll) do (
set filename=%%%%~nv
REM Do something that if fails changes the errorlevel
if !errorlevel! neq 0 if /i "!filename:Microsoft=!"=="!filename!"  (
 goto :error
)
)
```

Please note the thing to be careful is not to do anything that might change the errorlevel before using it, including echoing it...